# How to immediatly set a variable in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-6, eager-loading

Briefly, here's my associations:

```rb
Team:     has_many   :calendars
Calendar: has_many   :events
          belongs_to :team
Event:    belongs_to :calendar
```

I've a view where 2 forms are displayed:

1. one for adding a new Calendar, associated to a Team
2. one for adding a new Event, associated to a Calendar

In my controller, I set up variables with something like:

```rb
@team      = Team.find(params[:id])
@calendars = @team.calendars
@calendar  = @team.calendars.build
```

But in my view, `@calendar` is called **before** `@calendars`

```rb
<%= render partial: 'calendars/form', locals: { calendar:  @calendar,  ... } %>
<%= render partial: 'events/form',    locals: { calendars: @calendars, ... } %>
```

Thus in the `events/form` partial, the `<select>` tag contains a line for each calendar, plus one for the newly built calendar (which is empty, baah, ugly).

---

**QUESTION**: How could I set (eager load ?) the `@calendars` so it does not contains non-prersisted records ?

---

A simple solution that does not immediately set the `@calendars` variable, but at least does not pollute it:

```rb
@calendar = Calendar.new(team_id: @team.id)
```

Comment: why not just filter them out `@calendars = @team.calendars.where.not(id: nil)`

Comment: @dbugger that creates an additional db query. Better would be to just use `@calendars.select(&:persisted?)` or `@calendars.reject(&:new_record?)` if you want to go down that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use `eager_load` and to simply avoid building the record off the collection:

```ruby
@team      = Team.eager_load(:calendars)
                 .find(params[:id])
@calendars = @team.calendars
@calendar  = Calender.new(team: @team)
```

Or you can use `dup` to avoid mutating the original object:

```ruby
@team      = Team.eager_load(:calendars)
                 .find(params[:id])
@calendars = @team.calendars
@calendar  = @team.calendars.dup.new(team: @team)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`load`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load) to immediately load the records from the database.

```
@team      = Team.find(params[:id])
@calendars = @team.calendars.load
@calendar  = @team.calendars.build
```